# How to use multi db context in generic repository?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository

I've got multiple SQL Server databases and I need to use all of them in my generic repository.All of databases are on the same server

I got a generic repository In my project which has accepted a dbcontext, so i cann't be able to get query on another db context.how to separate classes to use specific `DbContext`?

For example :

```
// use dbContext 01
Public class sample01 
{

}

// use dbContext 02
Public class sample02
{

}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple Servers, multiple Databases in 1 server,...? It’s quite unclear, what your issue is.

Comment: Create generic repository functions such way which accept DbContext as parameter. Please provide us more clear idea about what exactly you want to do. So we can help you. Thanks.